# How to connect Azure Service Bus with Qpid Proton Java?

Tags: java, azureservicebus, qpid

I need to connect Azure service Bus for sending messages. I followed [given example](https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton-j/blob/0.26.0/examples/reactor/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/proton/example/reactor/Send.java)  and changed only host name to `amqps://XXX:XXX@abcd.servicebus.windows.net/queueName`

While running the Send class, i am getting below error. I tried a lot but could not solve the issue.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.HandlerException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No address provided for Connection
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.run(ReactorImpl.java:357)
>     at org.apache.qpid.proton.example.reactor.Send.main(Send.java:151)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No address provided for
>   Connection    at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.IOHandler.handleBound(IOHandler.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.IOHandler.onUnhandled(IOHandler.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.onConnectionBound(BaseHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
>     ... 4 more

sample code:

```
package org.apache.qpid.proton.example.reactor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.BufferOverflowException;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

import org.apache.qpid.proton.Proton;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp.messaging.AmqpValue;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp.transport.ErrorCondition;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Connection;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Delivery;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Event;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Sender;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.Session;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.message.Message;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.Handshaker;
import org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.Reactor;

// This is a send in terms of low level AMQP events.
public class Send extends BaseHandler {

    private class SendHandler extends BaseHandler {

        private final Message message;
        private int nextTag = 0;

        private SendHandler(Message message) {
            this.message = message;

            // Add a child handler that performs some default handshaking
            // behaviour.
            add(new Handshaker());
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionInit(Event event) {
            Connection conn = event.getConnection();

            // Every session or link could have their own handler(s) if we
            // wanted simply by adding the handler to the given session
            // or link
            Session ssn = conn.session();

            // If a link doesn't have an event handler, the events go to
            // its parent session. If the session doesn't have a handler
            // the events go to its parent connection. If the connection
            // doesn't have a handler, the events go to the reactor.
            Sender snd = ssn.sender("sender");
            conn.open();
            ssn.open();
            snd.open();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLinkFlow(Event event) {
            Sender snd = (Sender)event.getLink();
            if (snd.getCredit() > 0) {
                byte[] msgData = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        length = message.encode(msgData, 0, msgData.length);
                        break;
                    } catch(BufferOverflowException e) {
                        msgData = new byte[msgData.length * 2];
                    }
                }
                byte[] tag = String.valueOf(nextTag++).getBytes();
                Delivery dlv = snd.delivery(tag);
                snd.send(msgData, 0, length);
                dlv.settle();
                snd.advance();
                snd.close();
                snd.getSession().close();
                snd.getSession().getConnection().close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransportError(Event event) {
            ErrorCondition condition = event.getTransport().getCondition();
            if (condition != null) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + condition.getDescription());
            } else {
                System.err.println("Error (no description returned).");
            }
        }
    }

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final Message message;

    private Send(String host, int port, String content) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        message = Proton.message();
        message.setBody(new AmqpValue(content));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReactorInit(Event event) {
        // You can use the connection method to create AMQP connections.

        // This connection's handler is the SendHandler object. All the events
        // for this connection will go to the SendHandler object instead of
        // going to the reactor. If you were to omit the SendHandler object,
        // all the events would go to the reactor.
        event.getReactor().connectionToHost(host, port, new SendHandler(message));
         //event.getReactor().connectionToHost(host, port, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 5672;
        String host = "amqps://XXX:XXX@abcd.servicebus.windows.net/queueName"; // Only changed hostname

        if (args.length > 0) {
            String[] parts = args[0].split(":", 2);
            host = parts[0];
            if (parts.length > 1) {
                port = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            }
        }
        String content = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : "Hello World!";

        Reactor r = Proton.reactor(new Send(host, port, content));
        r.run();

    }

}
```

Comment: Without the full exception stack trace it is difficult to help you. Post the full stack of the exception.  Also enabling Proton-J's protocol trace feature by setting the environment variable (not Java system property) PN_TRACE_FRM to true, which will cause Proton to emit frame logging to stdout.

Comment: That's a problem. i am getting one liner error that is "Error: org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: connection aborted".  i even added "PN_TRACE_FRM=1" as environment variable but still i am getting one line error.

Comment: Could you please suggest, am i passing correct URL as host. i am worried about this.

Comment: @k-wall - finally i got the error details. I updated my post. Could you please take a look on above error and suggest your opinion.

Comment: @k-wall - Could you please suggest, how can i create SASL connection with qpid proton java. Sudo code will help a lot, please throw some input !!

Comment: You are misusing the Proton Reactor API. org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.Reactor#connectionToHost does not accept a connection URL.  It accepts a hostname as illustrated in the example you cite.  It you are looking to authenticate, you need to configure SASL.  There isn't currently a proton reactor example that illustrates this, but the comments on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PROTON-1606  should help.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, and for a more modern version of the library, but I struggled to find this answer myself. See below for a basic example that works as of today with Qpid Proton-J2, derived from the sample code here.

```
package com;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Client;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Connection;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.ConnectionOptions;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Delivery;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Message;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Receiver;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.Sender;
import org.apache.qpid.protonj2.client.exceptions.ClientException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientException {
        final String serverHost = System.getProperty("HOST", "YOUR_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE_HERE.servicebus.windows.net");
        final int serverPort = Integer.getInteger("PORT", 5671);
        final String address = System.getProperty("ADDRESS", "YOUR_QUEUE_NAME_HERE");

        final Client client = Client.create();

        final ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.sslOptions().sslEnabled(true);
        options.user("RootManageSharedAccessKey");
        options.password("YOUR_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_HERE");

        Connection connection = client.connect(serverHost, serverPort, options);
        Sender sender = connection.openSender(address);
        sender.send(Message.create("Hello World"));

        Receiver receiver = connection.openReceiver(address);
        Delivery delivery = receiver.receive();
        Message<String> received = delivery.message();
        System.out.println("Received message with body: " + received.body().toString());
    }
}
```